# Compare table name with column values in pgsql

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in which i enter all the names of the tables from my database, now i want to compare those table names with actual database tables:

Table Name: object_table
object_type(name of field)
employee (value)
department (value)

Table Name: employee
name (name of field in employee table)

Table Name: department
dept_name (name of field in department table)

i want to write a query which select and compare the data from the object_table, those tables that are in the database.

thanks

Comment: Not clear what you trying to achieve with this and why just querying [pg_class](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html) won't work?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to replicate functionality that is already built in: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html